# Closing a dialog mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dialog

I have en dialog box where there is an CKEditor inside. But i can't get it to fire the HTTPPost on the partialView.

```
 <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("Description")">
@Html.CKEditor("text", (string)ViewBag.BodyText, "toolbar:'Full'", new { cols = 2000, rows = 5000 })
<p>
<input type="submit"  value="@Resources.Resources.ProjectCreateDescriptionSave" onclick="@Html.CKEditorSubmitButtonUpdateFunction();" class="close"/>
</p>
</form>
```

It requires the class="close" but if it's in the input it closes but dosen't fire the httppost. But if i remove the class="close" it works prefect. IS there an way to combine them?

Comment: just a hit in the dark.. try adding this class ="close" in jquery (if you are using jquery)

Comment: I have tried that. With the same result. The reason i think is that the @Html.CKEditorSubmitButtonUpdateFunction(); dosent get exercuted correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a mistake in your click event.

```
onclick="@Html.CKEditorSubmitButtonUpdateFunction();"
```

Should read

```
onclick="CKEditorSubmitButtonUpdateFunction();"
```

Where `CKEditorSubmitButtonUpdateFunction()` is the name of your javascript function. There is no need for the appended @Html section.

Edit: and really you shouldnt need an onclick event there? Your form handles the post event `action="@Url.Action("Description")"`

Comment: The CKEditorSubmitButtonUpdateFunction() is an CKEditor that is getting me the correct text from the editor.

Comment: When I used CKEditor (with MVC3) I never needed to do this. So is it working now without the `@Html`?